# Linkedlist polynomial why my output only print first term

Tags: java, data-structures

I just wrote a program that add two polynomial linked-list. my output only prints first term of the polynomials.

I cannot figure out what bug is. I want to get some help here. could someone tell what's wrong with my code.

```
public void addNode(int cof, int exp) {
    PNode node = new PNode(cof, exp);
    if (first == null) {
        first = last = node;
        return;
    }
    last.next = node;
    last = node;
}
public PolynomialLinkedList add(PolynomialLinkedList s) {
    PolynomialLinkedList sum = new PolynomialLinkedList();

    //implement this method
    PNode list1 = first;
    PNode list2 = s.first;
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.exp == list2.exp) {
            sum.addNode(list1.coe + list2.coe, list1.exp);
            list1 = list1.next;
            list2 = list2.next;
        } else if (list1.exp > list2.exp) {
            sum.addNode(list1.coe, list1.exp);
            list1 = list1.next;
        } else if (list2.exp > list1.exp) {
            sum.addNode(list2.coe, list2.exp);
            list2 = list2.next;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Where is your print method (or toString)?

Answer (score 2):

If one of the lists finishes first, the rest of the items in other list are ignored and are not getting added to the sum.

Add additional loops

```
while(list1 != null) {
 sum.addNode(list1.coe,list1.exp);
            list1=list1.next;
}
```

and

```
while(list2 != null) {
 sum.addNode(list2.coe,list2.exp);
            list2=list2.next;
}
```